# Should there be a "not an answer" option in the "Share Feedback" section of the review queues?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, first-answers

Whilst reviewing the new ["First Answers" review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/) I've come across related questions in the answer section of a question.

When clicking the "Share Feedback" option there's nothing that covers these types of "answers" and no "flag" option.

What would be an appropriate action in these circumstances?

Comment: Is this a new Queue?

Comment: @yivi There's a new [first answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/) queue, yes.

Comment: And without a "flag" option. Beautiful. :(

Comment: Will be fixed soon-ish. [\[tag:status-planned\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369017)

Comment: Get's even better: You can't close-vote questions in the First Questions queue...

Comment: @yivi Yes, First Posts was split into Questions and Answers. Very recently. [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that the Flag option is available below the post...

> What would be an appropriate action in these circumstances?

You should flag as "Not an answer", optionally leave an explanatory comment yourself, then review as "Looks OK" to complete the review.

---

I have a [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/165261) over at Meta Stack Exchange to add some sort of better handling of non-answers in the First answers queue.

Comment: If a fellow devs already leave a community comment, should I upvote it and click "Looks OK" as well? Previously this action is seen as "Reviewed" not "Looks OK".

Comment: To me, it feels a bit strange to mark such an answer as "looks OK", even after doing the flagging/commenting. The answer itself does not look okay. The definition of "looks ok" is that "[the] answer is good as-is and not low quality." Although a comment/flag may have attempted to highlight the the not-ok answer, I do not think the comment/flag can be classed as part of the answer and to be considered in the evaluation of whether the "answer" looks ok or not. Wouldn't a review of "looks ok" on an answer that is not an answer therefore be wrong? Or have I misunderstood something here...?

Comment: FYI: I created [a separate (but closely related) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411061/reintroduce-im-done-to-the-first-answers-review-queue) to propose reintroducing the "I'm Done" button, since "Looks OK" isn't an intuitive option after flagging an answer. In [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411067/3025856), I include a link to [@Ryan-M's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369036#369036) as well as the response from the product team.