# Reintroduce "I'm Done" to the First Answers review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, first-answers

In the legacy *First Posts* review queue, if you flagged a post or added a comment, you could click *I'm Done* to continue, instead of *Looks OK*. In the new *First answers* review queue, however, this is no longer an option. Instead, you *must* choose between:

- Looks OK
- Edit
- Share feedback

  - Answer is unclear
  - Answer needs supporting information

None of these options make sense, however, if you've either

- Flagged an answer, or
- Left a custom comment.

The *Share feedback* option is the closest, but it forces you to choose between two canned comments that don't make sense for e.g. *Not an Answer*, *Rude or Abusive*, or *Spam*. We can leave a custom comment, of course, but the only way to proceed is to select either *Looks OK* (it doesn't) or *Skip*.

I propose fixing this by either:

1. Reintroducing the *I'm Done* option, or
2. Adding a *No Comment* option to *Share feedback*, similar to the *Low Quality Answers* queue.

Optionally, this could be enabled *only* if the reviewer flagged the post, upvoted an existing comment, or left a new comment—which is similar to how the *I'm Done* option worked previously (though it was also enabled if you voted on the post itself).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on Meta.SE with [status-planned]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369037/348196

Comment: Also related: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/348196) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369063/348196).

Comment: Given that a high number of first answers are new users who do not have rep to comment, there is a high proportion of non-answers so it is staggering to see that there is no non-answer flag as an option.

Comment: FYI: I’ve summarized the two main relevant proposals from the Meta SE threads in [my answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411067/3025856), alongside the product team’s response.

Comment: If a moderator happens to see this: This issue has since been resolved by the product team (see update in [my answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411067/3025856)) and can be marked as `[status-completed]`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Update

- **2021-09-08:** The product team has added an "Other Action" button to the *New Questions* and *New Answers* review queues. This is disabled (grayed out) until an action is taken, such as flagging the post, adding a comment, or upvoting an existing comment. The extended "Share Feedback" options haven't yet been deployed.

  [image: Screenshot of "Other Action"]

---

### Original Answer

[Per @41686d6564's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411061/reintroduce-im-done-to-the-first-answers-review-queue#comment862728_411061), [this issue has already been raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369037#369037) ([multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/348196) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369063/348196)) on [the original Stack Exchange thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) announcing the reorganization of the First Posts review queue.

#### “I’m Done” Button

In response to [@Bill Tür’s proposal to bring back the "I'm done" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369037#369037), Stack Overflow staff member [@kristinalustig](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/344828/kristinalustig) [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release#comment1231494_369037):

> Agreed that this is a good idea. I'm going to be working on adding this option back in. Might take a few days, but I'll mark this as status-planned. Thanks for the feedback.

#### “Share Feedback” Options

In response to [@Ryan M’s proposal to add more “Share Feedback” options to address non-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/724530), @kristinalustig [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release#comment1231494_369037):

> We added flags back in, and we're going to be adding other options back in as well. I'm going to mark this as status-completed.

Based on this, this issue is not only known to the product team, but is in the process of being fixed. A resolution will hopefully be available next week or two.